# Mac procNotFound (-600) error when opening a file

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

I have a program (P1) that will launch another program (P2) from it.  When it does P1 and P2 are part of the same process group (when viewed with the activity monitor).

I then have a file that is associated with P2.  When I double click the file the OS fails to open the file in P2.  I get a finder error "The application P2 can't be opened. -600".

If I do not have P2 launched and double click on the file it works fine.

If I launch P2 from the finder and then double click the file it works fine.

It only fails when I launch P2 from P1 and then double click on the file.

Any ideas?

Everything works fine on 10.7 it stopped working on 10.8.

Thanks
Brian

Comment: How does P1 launch P2? Fork and exec? `NSTask`? Launch Services or `NSWorkspace`?

Comment: We Fork then build up the command and arguments (command is open P1.app) and then execvp() with the command and arguments.

Comment: Since the `open` command is just a wrapper around Launch Services, why don't you directly use the Launch Services API?